# Is there a way to find / update a row based on column values instead of the Row ID?

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

I have a C# app that sends data to Smartsheet.  At the moment, it's just inserting rows, based on the following:

```
Row rowA = new Row.AddRowBuilder(null, true, null, null, null).SetCells(cellsA).Build();
smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows(_SheetID, new Row[] { rowA });
```

There are two columns that are essentially the keys for the data, and I'd like to be able to update a row if it exists (WHERE field1 = 'key1' and field2 = 'key2'), and if no row exists with those two field values, do a row insert.

Is it possible to do an update / insert like this?  Keep in mind, I'm very new to the Smartsheet API - still finding my way...

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do this manually today.  There isn't a currenty way to ask the API to do this for you.

- Irwin